# Multiple artifacts fail to trigger release pipeline

Tags: azure-devops, azure-devops-pipelines

I have a pipeline with 2 artifacts (2 different Universal Packages in the same feed). The CD trigger is enabled for both, however neither of those 2 packages will trigger the pipeline.

Here’s a screenshot of the pipeline:

[image]

Am I missing something in the configuration of this pipeline?

Comment: After enable CD trigger, did you save the pipeline? Were you able to see new versions of the package in the artifact? Please try to create a new release pipeline to see whether you could reproduce this issue. I tested in my Azure DevOps Service, the trigger worked as expected.

Comment: What is your Default version when you add the Universal Package artifact? The Latest? Did you generate a new version in the feed?

Comment: apparently I cannot use a package that doesn't exist yet. In other words, I cannot simply specify the name of the package by typing it, it must be selected from the dropdown. This means that you cannot create the artifact trigger as long as the package hasn't been published to the feed, in the correct view.

Comment: @Jonas Do you mean you have found the root cause that you typo a package that doesn't exist?

Comment: @CeceDong-MSFT, not a typo, I simply typed the name of the package that I knew was going to be published at some point in the future, but wasn't there yet when I created the pipeline. So it looks like if you create the pipeline before the package exists, the pipeline will never get triggered when the package is eventually published. That may not be a bug but I guess it would be very helpful to at least have it mentioned in the documentation somewhere.

Comment: @Jonas You are correct that the package should exists when you specify the artifact, and you may submit your idea at website https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/idea/post.html?space=21.